# Large sample properties of classical estimator for single scale parameter

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, point-estimation

This question was first posted on [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341163/large-sample-properties-of-classical-estimator-for-scale-parameter) and I was told in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341163/large-sample-properties-of-classical-estimator-for-scale-parameter?noredirect=1#comment9057075_4341163) it would be a good question on Stats Stackexchange, since it comes from the well-established theory of point estimation.

Suppose $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ are non-negative and have a joint probability density
$$\frac{1}{\sigma^n}f\bigl(\frac{x}{\sigma}\bigr)=\frac{1}{\sigma^n}f\bigl(\frac{x_1}{\sigma}, \frac{x_2}{\sigma},\ldots, \frac{x_n}{\sigma}\bigr),$$
where $f$ is known, and $\sigma>0$ is the only unknown scale parameter. In classical decision theory, we may choose an estimator $d$ to minimize the risk
$$\mathbb{E}[L(\sigma,d)|\sigma],$$
here $L(\sigma,d)$ is the loss function. For example, Stein’s loss $L(\sigma,d)=d/\sigma-\log(d/\sigma)-1$. Then the minimum risk estimator can be written as
$$d=X_{1}/\mathbb{E}[X_{1}|\sigma=1,Z],$$
where $Z=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$ with $Z_i=X_i/X_n$ is the maximal invariant.

With the different choice of loss function, we may get a different minimum risk estimator. So far they are just some well-established results in the theory of point estimation. Usually, in large sample, we prefer MLE since $f$ is known and MLE is the most efficient $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimator in this case. I’m just curious about the limiting behavior of above kind of estimators. Intuitively, it is consistent. But what is the convergence rate and limiting distribution? I’ve searched for literature but got no general results about this question.

I know the limiting behavior depends on $f$, in a special case that $f$ is normal, the above estimator coincides with MLE. Will above estimator sometimes have a faster/slower convergence rate than MLE if $f$ satisfies certain conditions? Any references or ideas are welcome!

Comment: Could you explain the notation $d=X_{1}/\mathbb{E}[X_{1}|\sigma=1,Z]$ what is $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}|\sigma=1,Z]$ is it a statistic that follows from the observations?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Yes. Say for example we have two observations $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$. Given $\sigma=1$, the joint distribution is known (albeit it may not be the true distribution). Maybe I should change a different notation for better illustration, call $(Y_{1}, Y_{2})$ an independent copy drawn from this joint distribution ($f$ with $\sigma=1$). Then $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}|\sigma=1,Z]$ is just the conditional expectation of $Y_{1}$ given $Y_{1}/Y_{2}=X_{1}/X_{2}$, hence a function of observations. Detailed derivation of this estimator is in Chapter 3 of Lehmann's *Theory of Point Estimation*.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at it but I think that you may want to look at some of the work by Devroye and Lugosi on utilizing the $L_1$ loss.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks for your advice!

Comment: There can be at most one scale parameter in a model, so by "only unknown scale parameter" should we understand that $\sigma$ is the *sole* parameter in the model or not? When it's the sole parameter, consider the scale family for a Bernoulli$(1/2)$ variable: the chance you cannot determine $\sigma$ *exactly* in a sample of size $n$ is the chance that all results are zero, equal to $2^{-n}:$ that's exponential-rate convergence. Is that a relevant example or do you wish perhaps to limit the scope of the question to continuous distributions, perhaps with all positive numbers in their support?

Comment: @whuber Yes, meaning $\sigma$ is the sole parameter. I've never thought about such kind of situation that the parameter can be exactly determined before. Your example is quite interesting. However, for this question in the post, I think the scope is narrowed to continuous distributions, more specifically, having a $\sqrt{n}$-normal MLE estimator.

Comment: It's worth considering the standard textbook example (amply covered here on CV) of the family of Uniform$(0,\sigma)$ distributions: there is a simple MLE for $\sigma$ and it is easy to analyze asymptotically.

Comment: @whuber I understand there could are some cases that MLE exists but fails to be $\sqrt{n}$-normal, for example in this uniform case, because when we prove asymptomatic normality we do a Taylor expansion, which requires MLE to be an interior point of parameter set. I was trying to say in this post I’m interested only in the distributions that are not that ``weird” in the sense that classical assumptions for $\sqrt{n}$-normality are satisfied.

Comment: That's fine--but you need to specify your constraints in the question itself--clearly and completely.  Otherwise you might start getting answers where your response is "but no, I didn't mean that," and then people get upset because you have caused them to waste their time.

Comment: @whuber Sorry I didn't provide a complete explanation in the question. I'll keep in mind and make later questions (if any) more explicit as I can. Anyways thank you for your help! :)